# for loop wont run on startup of javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a todo list and store it in local storage so it gets saved.
I run the get() and list() function on startup to pull it out of localStorage and list it. Problem is that the for loop won't run in the list() function. Once I put in a new item and run the newItem() function it pulls out of localStorage and lists it all fine. Any ideas?

```
get();
list();
function Todo(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.completed = false;
}

function newItem(){
    var t = new Todo(document.getElementById("newItem").value)
    items.push(t)
    save();
    console.log(items)

}

function save(){
    var save = JSON.stringify(items)
    localStorage.setItem("localsave", save)
    list();
}

function list(name){
    var html = "";
    console.log(items)
    for(var i in items){
     var todo = items[i];
     var name = todo.name
     var completed = todo.completed;
     html += "<li>"+name+""+completed+"</li>"
    }
    $("#ul").html(html);
}
function get(){
    var temp = localStorage.getItem("localsave")
    items = JSON.parse(temp)


}
```

HTML document looks like this if anyone is interested in that

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="todo.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="javascript:newItem()">
    <input type="text" id="newItem" name="newItem" placeholder="New item">

</form>
<ul id="ul">

</ul>
```

Comment: `items` is a global variable ?

Comment: Just to clarify i want the items in localStorage to be listed on startup without running the newItem function

Comment: i mean it works after running the newItem function so that shouldnt be a problem Tahawi

Comment: It is difficult to check without the info about how when this JS is included in the page. Can you provide that too?

Comment: `localStorage.getItem("localsave")` might return `null` if the stored data does not exist already. You should handle that case.

Comment: What does `console.log(items)` output?

Comment: It outputs an array with all the items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code runs the java script code first then it renders the  HTMl elements.

this line had been executed first , before the control with "ul" id was rendered , so it has fetched the data from storage already but can't view them in the not rendered "ui".

```
$("#ul").html(html);
```

so your code should call `todo.js` after rendering the HTML elements like that:

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
       <form method="post" action="javascript:newItem()">
        <input type="text" id="newItem" name="newItem" placeholder="New item">

    </form>
    <ul id="ul">

</ul>

    <script src="todo.js"></script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonas Wilms mentioned you need to handle the null value from store. Your get function needs to be something like below.

```
 get() {
    var temp = localStorage.getItem("localsave")
    if (temp) {
      items = JSON.parse(temp)
    }
    else {
      items = [];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is you want.

```
list();

function Todo(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.completed = false;
}

function newItem(){
    var items = get();
    var t = new Todo(document.getElementById("newItem").value)
    items.push(t);
    save(items);
    console.log('saving items', items);
}

function save(items){
    var save = JSON.stringify(items)
    localStorage.setItem("localsave", save)
    list();
}

function list(name){
    var html = "";
    var items = get();
    if(items.length > 0){
     for(var i in items){
      var todo = items[i];
      var name = todo.name;
      var completed = todo.completed;
      html += "<li>"+name+""+completed+"</li>"
     }
     $("#ul").html(html);
    }
    console.log('listing items', items);
}

function get(){
    var temp = localStorage.getItem("localsave");
    if(temp){
      return JSON.parse(temp);
    }else{
      return [];
    }
}
```